# java 6 on mac 10.5.8 using SoyLatte

Tags: java, macos, osx-leopard, java-6

If I install SoyLatte on MAC 10.5.8, On command line I can see the version as 1.6.0
However the Safari Browser extension still shows the old java version.
In Java Preference also I am not able to see Java 6 version.
How do I update browsers to run under java 6.
Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

SoyLatte is not a full replacement for Java on OS X - just a proof of concept - and the real port of OpenJDK is targetting OS X 10.6 and up.

For OS X 10.5 you are best off with the official Apple offerings which according to http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4739?viewlocale=da_DK includes Java 6.

Comment: Apple still provides Java 6 for recent platforms.  Oracle will provide Java 7 for OS X in the same way that it currently does for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

OSX 10.5 originally only included Java 1.4 and 5 [OSX Java 1.5 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaLeopardRN/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get later versions you need to install the updates the [latest](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1359) provide 1.6.0_26 and  1.5.0_30,albeit 1.6 is for Intel 64 bit machines only.